# How to get the Azure AD authenticated user’s username and email

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, active-directory

I have built a .Net Core web application that authenticates the user against Azure AD. After successful authentication I want to access the authenticated user’s details, such as username / email.

I can’t figure out how to do that. Can anyone help? Thanks. I am using C# by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These values should be provided through *claims*. In ASP.NET Core you can access a user’s claim through the `User` object that is available from most framework locations like controllers, Razor pages, or Razor views.

The email and username should be available through the [`ClaimTypes.Email`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes.email?view=netstandard-2.1) and [`ClaimTypes.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimtypes.name?view=netstandard-2.1) claims respectively. So you should be able to do this to retrieve those values:

```
string email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
string name = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
```

You could also loop through the `User.Claims` collection to see what claims your authentication provider included. For example, you could do this in a Razor view to quickly list all available claims:

```
<ul>
  @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
  {
    <li><strong>@claim.Type:</strong> @claim.Value</li>
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. This worked. In my case, the Claim Type that I needed was called "preferred_username".